# Cocos2d: Animation based on accelerometer

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer

Anyone know of any good up to date tutorials out there that show how can one animate a sprite based on accelerometer movement. I want to animate a bird to sway to the position the device was pointed to. For example if the player decides to move the bird to the left via the accelerometer I would like for my bird to play an animation that is swaying to the left.

```
// Accelerometer
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration   *)acceleration { 
birdSpeedY = 9.0 + acceleration.x*15;
birdSpeedX = -acceleration.y*20;
}

// Updating bird based on accelerometer
-(void)updateBird { 
float maxY = winSize.height - bird.contentSize.height/2;
float minY = bird.contentSize.height/2;
float newY = bird.position.y + birdSpeedY;
newY = MIN(MAX(newY, minY), maxY);

float maxX = winSize.width - bird.contentSize.width/2;
float minX = bird.contentSize.width/2;
float newX = bird.position.x + birdSpeedX;
newX = MIN(MAX(newX, minX), maxX);

bird.position = ccp(newX, newY);
}

// Making background scroll automatically 
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt { 
[self updateBird];

CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(-100, 0);
parallaxNode.position = ccpAdd(parallaxNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));


}


-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
   winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    CCSpriteFrameCache *cache=[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
    [cache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"birdAtlas.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *framesArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        NSString *frameName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bird%d.png", i];
        id frameObject=[cache spriteFrameByName:frameName];
        [framesArray addObject:frameObject];
    }
    // animation object
    id animObject=[CCAnimation animationWithFrames:framesArray delay:0.1];

    // animation action
    id animAction=[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animObject restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
    animAction=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animAction];


    bird=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bird1.png"];
    bird.position=ccp(60,160);



    CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode=[CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"birdAtlas.png"];
    [self addChild:batchNode z:100];
    [batchNode addChild:bird];

    [bird runAction:animAction];

    self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES; 
    [self scheduleUpdate]; 

    [self addScrollingBackgroundWithTileMapInsideParallax];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the Accelerometer methods with it and change the position of the Sprite using ccp(). You also need to know is that project for the Landscape or Portrait in the Mode.
You Can Try the Stuff below

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer*)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration*)acceleration
{   
    [lbl setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"X=>%.2lf Y=>%.2lf",(double)acceleration.x,(double)acceleration.y]];
    double x1= -acceleration.y *10;
    double y1=  acceleration.x *15;
    if(acceleration.x >0.05)
    {
         y1*=spped_incr; // Make Movement Here

    }
    [Sprite_Name runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1f position:ccpAdd(ccp(x1,y1), Sprite_Name.position)]];
}
```

The Above Stuff is for the Landscape Mode.... if You need in Portrait Mode you need to change the Axis and use the TRY & Error Method.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try it out and also my game is going to be on landscape so I wont have to change anything.

Comment: I am really stomped can you please help me out on how I would modify your code to fit mine. I posted some code above the page where I ask ed the question so please check it out. Sorry if this bugs you I am new to programming in general and I have a hard time seeing how some things work.